# browserify + babel v6 + react + gulp not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to get all of these things working together, it worked previously so am a little baffed.

I already have all the dependencies installed that are required in the new babel v6 changes.

**dev/index.js**

```
import React from "react"
```

**Whole gulp task**

```
gulp.task("js", function () {
    var bundler = through2.obj(function (file, enc, next) {
        browserify(file.path, {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
            bundleExternal: false
        })
        .transform('babelify', {
            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        })
        .bundle(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            file.contents = res;
            next(null, file);
        });
    });

    return gulp
        .src(path.join(config.dir.src, config.dir.client, config.dir.js, "index.js"))
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(bundler)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.dir.dist, config.dir.js)))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

**Output index.js**

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

var _react = require("react");

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

},{"react":undefined}]},{},[1]);
```

**Package.json**

```
"babel-core": "^6.7.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
```

Comment: lol thats the fastest downvote I've ever seen, let alone received. Any chance I could improve the question then you give me the downvote :)? Ha another one, I really don't think this question is that bad

Comment: Not me, but here's an advice: " it worked previously", that does not really help us. What did you do since ? (btw, I recommend you to use webpack instead of browserify, at least for react, but that's another story)

Comment: Reading an article now on webpack :) Previously was version 5 of babel.

Comment: What exactly are you saying isn't working? That code looks fine to me, you just aren't using the `React` variable for anything.